# Rejecting a promise from inside a callback

Tags: javascript, promise

I've got a Promise function

```
function test()
{
   let promise = new Promise<string>(function(resolve, reject)
        {
            func( resolve, reject );
        });
   return promise;
}

function func(resolve, reject )
{
    let reject2 = reject;

    window.on( "error", (msg) =>
    {
        console.log("inside error");
        reject2();
    } );

    // other stuff
}
```

In an error condition - I'm trying to reject the original promise.

It seems to work - but evey time I create the error condition, the "inside error" message gets printed that many times.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing `new Promise(func)`?

Comment: I don't understand this pattern. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I've updated - hopefully makes some sense

Comment: `window.on` is not a function? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Running your code with (`test().then(console.log).catch(console.error)`) and firing the error event, the inside error only logs once.

Comment: The reason why it gets printed that many times is you are attaching that many event handlers every time you call .on method (from whatever library), you should attach it once.

Comment: Thank you - that was part of the problem. I did have an "off" - but I changed the event name and forgot to change it for the "off" - that problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to remove the handler after it fires.

Something like this:

```
function test()
{ 
    let promise = new Promise<string>(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        func( resolve, reject );
    });
    return promise;
}

function func(resolve, reject )
{
  let reject2 = reject;

  let handler = (msg) =>
  {
    console.log("inside error");
    reject2();
    window.off( "error", handler ); //removing the handler here
  } 

  window.on( "error", handler);

 // other stuff
}
```

But this approach has the problem that will remove all registered handlers at any error and I don't know if this is desired.

Comment: This is the correct answer. When you use `something.on`, that callback can fire 1 or more times, and it will stay connected until it's removed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do, my guess was too long to put in comments, so give this a shot. Quite sure this is an A->B->C problem.

```
!function(){
    let errorAttached = false,
        currentReject = null;
    function test()
    {
       let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
            {
                func( resolve, reject );
            });
       return promise;
    }

    function func(resolve, reject )
    {
        let currentReject = reject;
        if(!errorAttached) {
            window.on( "error", (msg) =>
            {
                console.log("inside error");
                currentReject();
            });
            errorAttached = true;
        }

        // other stuff
    }
}();
```

Answer (score -1):

I did not understand why you are creating a callback function to treat the result of your promise. I've never used this way. Perhaps you want to cancel your promise when something happens to the page. In this case, you could follow the example on this page. You will have a bunch of way to implement it.

https://blog.bloomca.me/2017/12/04/how-to-cancel-your-promise.html

```js
class CancelablePromise {
  constructor(executor) {
    let _reject = null;
    const cancelablePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      _reject = reject;
      return executor(resolve, reject);
    });
    cancelablePromise.cancel = _reject;

    return cancelablePromise;
  }
}

// now lets work with the class
var cancelable = false;
const p = new CancelablePromise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(!cancelable)
      resolve(console.log('resolved!'));
  }, 2000);
})

p.catch(error => console.log(error.toString()));

setTimeout(() => {
  cancelable = true;
  p.cancel(new Error("Whoops!"));
}, 1000); // change by 3000 to be resolved
```

Comment: I'm listening to several events and i want to return the results on the first success or failure. One of the events is a setTimeout() just incase I don't get a response within a fixed time. The link you sent - seems to use a proprietary library - I have to use just core JS.

Comment: I added a class there. Work with the class and a flag to check things out. To call cancel you can use window events as you did on your function